# Google Sign in with Cordova on Android

Tags: angular, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using SignInWithRedirect from firebase to login to google using my Cordova app (initially I have an Angular app that's made into Cordova). Everything works in the browser but when I try on mobile it fails with

> The mobile app identifier is not registed for the current project.

Also if I go to the link given with the error in console log I get this

[image]

I have no idea why and tried everything, even created a new android app on firebase but nothing help.

I'm usign Cordova 8.0 and Android 6.4.0

Thanks!

[UPDATE] It was a syntax error in the config on Firebase now that's fixed but I've bumped into a new problem.

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "Error code: 24",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Error code: 24",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you register your android app in the Firebase Console for that project?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed this it was a small (2 letter) difference between some project config that did the problem. But now I bumped into a new one. I'll update the question with the new problem now.

Comment: Are you using *.page.link Firebase dynamic link domains?

Comment: @bojeil Yes I am, and I saw that and it's the right one. When I searched the error I couldn't find much but it looked like a firebase error which is unlikely.

Comment: There was an outage related to this. It should be solved by now: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/18003